# PHP - Load data to array

Tags: php, arrays, input, external

is possible load data to array from .txt?

**This is my .php file:**

```
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents('data.txt');
    $data = array(

    $file;

    );

?>
```

**This is data.txt file:**

```
    "1" => array('code', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'type', 'datetime', 'place1', 'place2', 'number1', 'number2', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'),  
    "2" => array('code', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'type', 'datetime', 'place1', 'place2', 'number1', 'number2', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'),  
    "3" => array('code', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'type', 'datetime', 'place1', 'place2', 'number1', 'number2', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3')
```

But it doesn´t work. Thanks for help.

Comment: File_get_contents returns a string which you'd have to manipulate in to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of better ways to do this.

### With JSON

data.json:

```
{
  "1": ['code', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'type', 'datetime', 'place1', 'place2', 'number1', 'number2', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
  "2": 'code', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'type', 'datetime', 'place1', 'place2', 'number1', 'number2', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3',
  "3": 'code', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'type', 'datetime', 'place1', 'place2', 'number1', 'number2', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'
}
```

PHP to read it:

```
<?php
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), true);
  var_dump($data)
```

### With a PHP data file

data.php

```
<?php
return [
    "1" => array('code', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'type', 'datetime', 'place1', 'place2', 'number1', 'number2', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'),  
    "2" => array('code', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'type', 'datetime', 'place1', 'place2', 'number1', 'number2', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3'),  
    "3" => array('code', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'phone', 'type', 'datetime', 'place1', 'place2', 'number1', 'number2', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3')
];
```

code to read it:

```
<?php
$data = include('data.php');
```

You could also use php's serialize, but it makes the data format a bit less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()`:

```
eval('$data = array(' . file_get_contents('data.txt') . ');');
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: I would avoid using eval whenever possible.

Comment: Me too. But I think without modifications of file content, it is the only way to do it.

Comment: Sorry Jessie, That's incorrect. There are a plethora of ways to accomplish this. Please stay away from eval. Its very unnecessary 99.9% of the time.